# List data within bracket - Freemarker

Tags: json, xml, freemarker

I am new to freemarker and trying to extract list of value defined within bracket. Example below..

alternative-id provider="group" level="episode" description="CHICAGO MED YR 5 (Sign) Ep 514">20595987</alternative-id

alternative-id provider="group" level="episode" description="CHICAGO MED YR 5 (U) Ep 514">20670620</alternative-id

Would like to list values within the ()

Output will be as below

Sign
U

OR

Sign,U

Couldn't get list command working to extract data.. it only extract data within ><
20595987
20670620

Comment: Please improve your question instead of asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this successfully on https://try.freemarker.apache.org/:

**Template**

```
<#assign bracketValues = data?matches("<alternative-id([\\w\\s\=\"]*)\\(([\\w\\s\\d]*)\\)")>
<#list bracketValues as b>
${b?groups[2]}<#sep>,</#list>
```

**Data model**

```
data = "<alternative-id provider=\"group\" level=\"episode\" description=\"CHICAGO MED YR 5 (Sign) Ep 514\">20595987</alternative-id><alternative-id provider=\"group\" level=\"episode\" description=\"CHICAGO MED YR 5 (U) Ep 514\">20670620</alternative-id>"
```

**Result**

```
Sign,U
```